# References for Stochastic Control for finance

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-control

What are some good references to study Stochastic Control with applications to Finance, like the Merton problem and other variants? Books or review papers?

Answer (score 6):

Peter Forsyth of UWaterloo is my favourite author on this topic (one of my top three in MathFin!)

[Personal Homepage with Lots of Papers](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Epaforsyt/)

Optimal allocation under wealth goals, optimal decumulation strategies, etc

I find his writing style very honest and open, yet to find a typo and the notation is super clear.

Comment: Thank you! I will keep an eye out for his papers in my journey of studying this area.

Answer (score 3):

Look into [Huyên Pham, Continuous-time Stochastic Control and Optimization with Financial Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540894993); [Salvatore Federico, Giorgio Ferrari, Luca Regis (Editors). Applications of Stochastic Optimal Control to Economics and Finance](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3039360582).

Comment: Thank you! I was able to get ahold of Pham's book and it appears to be what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

it is a bit late but the 2007 book "[Applied Stochastic Control of Jump Diffusions](https://%3Chttps://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-69826-5%3E)" from Oksendal and Sulem is quite good too.

Answer (score 0):

Best  Book in my opinion is to read 'Derivatives Principles and Practice' by Sundaram Das. Please buy it.

Comment: Looking through the table of contents, are you sure that the book covers stochastic control theory? It looks more like a similar version to Hull's book?